# Error with IO.popen and ffmepg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ffmpeg

I received files in mp3 (2 minutes/files) I want to concatenate together and create a bigger file. So I created my model a function to do this using ffmpeg and IO.popen

```
FileUtils.mkdir_p "#{Rails.root}/tmp/files"
imported_dir = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/files/#{SecureRandom.uuid}"
links.each_with_index do |link, index|
  file_path = "#{imported_dir}_#{index}#{File.extname(link)}"
  File.open(file_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file.write open(link).read
  end
  concat_list << "file '#{file_path}'\n"
end
File.open("#{imported_dir}.txt", 'w'){ |f| f.write(concat_list)}
io = IO.popen("#{Rails.root}/lib/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -f concat -i #{imported_dir}.txt -c copy #{imported_dir}.mp3").readlines
if sound = Sound.create(user_id: user.id, file: File.open("#{imported_dir}.mp3"), lang: lang, title: title)
  audio = FFMPEG::Movie.new("#{imported_dir}.mp3")
  if !audio.valid?
    puts "//_!_\\\\ Failed reading with ffmpeg (#{sound.id})#{sound.title} //_!_\\\\"
    return false
  end
end
```

the problem is that my .txt file containing the file path

```
file '/home/test/apps/example/releases/20150305224026/tmp/files/4dbe9707-cfef-467b-ab2c-a5e1e1165953_0.mp3'
```

created files as well but the final file is not created and i got the error message :

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/test/apps/example/releases/20150305224026/tmp/files/4dbe9707-cfef-467b-ab2c-a5e1e1165953.mp3
```

If anyone could help me

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the target directory exists and is writable by the user running your app.

Comment: The directory exist and the acces for the tmp directory : drwxrwxr-x  4 test test   4096 Mar  6 09:43 tmp and for the files directory : drwxrwxr-x   2 test test 4096 Mar  6 10:09 files The tmp/files directory is present in my Rails application but the txt was created just the concat doesnt work.

Comment: I'll add to this answer advice to check ffmpeg execution: path and execution rights. seems like ffmpeg wasn't executed at all. What was printed in stdout to  io pipe? Have you redirected stdin before ffmpeg execution?